# Without changing value formState isDirty changes to true

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

In the below snippet, what i am trying to do is, I am trying to add new field as dynamic using react hook form useFieldArray. But if I click append also the formState.isDirty changes to true without touching the field.

As per the understanding the isDirty should trigger when there is a change in the input field, but here the number of fields by default is 4 and it got increased to 5, But the new field is empty.

So what I am trying to solve is how to keep the isDirty false when I trigger append.
Make the submit field enabled when the user changes any value

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const { register, control, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      test: [
        { firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Luo", canDelete: false },
        { firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Luo", canDelete: false },
        { firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Luo", canDelete: false },
        { firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Luo", canDelete: false }
      ]
    }
  });
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "test"
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log("data", data);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <ul>
        {fields.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <input
                name={`test[${index}].firstName`}
                defaultValue={`${item.firstName}`} // make sure to set up defaultValue
                ref={register()}
              />
              <Controller
                as={<input />}
                name={`test[${index}].lastName`}
                control={control}
                defaultValue={item.lastName} // make sure to set up defaultValue
              />
              {item.canDelete && (
                <button type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>
                  Delete
                </button>
              )}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
      <section>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            append({ firstName: "", lastName: "", canDelete: true });
          }}
        >
          append
        </button>
      </section>

      <input type="submit" disabled={!formState.isDirty} />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-forked-23nfl)